# IndexedDB Fails when adding objects that contain element references

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, indexeddb

I'm writing an application for Google Chrome (targeted audience is an internal team) that allows a user to manipulate elements from within an iframe.  The user is able to use her mouse to select DOM elements and to perform various actions to them, such as changing colors, fonts, etc.

I'm using a `nodeIterator` method to select only elements that have IDs or class names.  Then for each of those elements, I add some element-specific properties to an object, and push that object to an array.  Then, I open an IndexedDB database and add each object in the array to the database.

My problem is this:  Everything works fine so long as I don't include a reference to the element in the object.

```
// Works fine
array.push({
     width : currentNode.offsetWidth,
    height : currentNode.offsetHeight,
       top : currentNode.style.top;
      left : currentNode.style.left;
});

// Doesn't work
array.push({
      elem : currentNode,
     width : currentNode.offsetWidth,
    height : currentNode.offsetHeight,
       top : currentNode.style.top;
      left : currentNode.style.left;
});
```

Google chrome fails silently (nothing in the console at all) after trying to add the first element to the IndexedDB store.

My question is this:  Has anyone else experienced this behavior and is this a browser-specific bug?

I'll distill my code to JSfiddle tomorrow.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IndexedDB [store structured clone](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#value-construct) of your object. Basically your data will converted into JSON object, these exclude Element or Node data type.

However fail silently is not an expected behaviour. Accordingly to the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm), it should throw DataCloneError.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any ideas as to how I can pass a reference to the element?

Comment: I will rather avoid reference pointer to element because of potential memory leak. The best option is ID as Kristof point out, if you could generate uniquely. The second best is NAME attribute, but I don't know how to retrieve efficiently in x-browser way. So it seems people are using CLASS name instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to save the DOM element? Can you just save the ID of the DOM element and retrieve the element back by its ID?

The indexeddb is only capable of storing data that doesn't have circular references. There is maybe one thing you can try. Sometime ago I wrote a [blog post](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/07/json-serialize-and-deserialize.html) on how you can serialize and deserialize functions to JSON. Maybe this can help you, but I would advace you not to store complete elements unless there is no other option. This will add a lot of unnecessary data into your database, and it's possible you'll lose information when serializing to JSON.

Comment: The user uses this application to alter CSS styles for elements. Those CSS styles are targeted using the ID and Class names, so I fear altering those since it could produce unexpected results. I'll think up some kind of work-around. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You should get an exception in chrome (I just tried on Chrome 23) from the put() itself, which means if you have an onerror handler, it won't get called because the exception gets called first:

i.e. if you have

```
req = db.transaction("foo", "readwrite").objectStore("foo").put({...data with dom nodes })
req.onsuccess = ...
req.onerror = ...
```

The exception will be thrown by the first line.

Comment: I am using the same version of Chrome, but I'm not using a `put` transaction. I'm adding the array data to the Object Store via the `store.add` transaction in Chrome's equivalent for `onupgradeneeded`.